# Using threadpool with thread completion updates inside a lock

Tags: c#, threadpool

Following several tutorials on threaded app development, I've implemented a small practice utility that uses both Task.Run, and `Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem` to recursively index a folder and generate a checksum manifest of all contained files.

While the application works well, I'm unable to get the UI to update during the portion that specifically uses a `threadpool`. The UI does update correctly using await `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` when using Task.Run.

The desired behavior is for the progress to continue to update within `ProcessChecksums` as each of the threadpool's threads finish their individual task.

```
int queuedThreads = 0;
object locker = new object();
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
List<string> lstFilePaths = new List<string>();
Manifest manifestData;
event Action<double> OnProgressChange;
event Action<string> OnStatusChange;
    
async void GenerateManifest(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    status = "Indexing Files";
    progress = 1;

    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    await Task.Run(() => Async_GenerateManifest(cancellationTokenSource.Token), cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    if (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
        Finished();
    }else{
        Cancelled();
    }
}
    
async Task Async_GenerateManifest(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }

    Async_IndexFiles(initialpath, cancellationToken);
        
    //Works Perfectly
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => {
        OnStatusChange("Generating Checksums");
        OnProgressChange(10);
    }));

    ProcessChecksums(cancellationToken);

    //Works Perfectly
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => {
        OnStatusChange("Saving Manifest");
        OnProgressChange(90);
    }));

    SaveManifestFile(cancellationToken);
}
    
void ProcessChecksums(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    List<FileData> lstFileData = new List<FileData>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lstFilePaths.Count; i++) {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }
            
        string s = lstFilePaths[i];
        lock (locker) queuedThreads++;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( x => {
            manifestData.AddFileData(new FileData(s, GenerateChecksum(s)));
        });
    }

    lock (locker) {
        while (queuedThreads > 0) {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }=
            Monitor.Wait(locker);
                
            //Can't use await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke as is inside a lock, doesn't update GUI while waiting.
            OnProgressChange((((queuedThreads - lstFilePaths.Count) * -1) / lstFilePaths.Count) - 0.2);
        }
    }
}

string GenerateChecksum(string filePath) {
    //Time-consuming checksum generation
    //...

    lock (locker) {
        queuedThreads--;
        Monitor.Pulse(locker);
    }

    return BitConverter.ToString(checksum);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard pattern for updating the UI with progress updates from a background thread is to use `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>`. The more modern approach has several benefits over direct use of `Dispatcher`.

```
// You'd want to set these while on the UI thread.
// E.g., in your constructor:
//   _percentProgress = new Progress<double>(value => ...);
//   _statusProgress = new Progress<string>(value => ...);
IProgress<double> _percentProgress;
IProgress<string> _statusProgress;

async void GenerateManifest(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  status = "Indexing Files";
  progress = 1;

  cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

  await Task.Run(() => GenerateManifest(cancellationTokenSource.Token));

  if (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
    Finished();
  }else{
    Cancelled();
  }
}

void GenerateManifest(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }

  Async_IndexFiles(initialpath, cancellationToken);

  _statusProgress?.Report("Generating Checksums");
  _percentProgress?.Report(10);

  ProcessChecksums(cancellationToken);

  _statusProgress?.Report("Saving Manifest");
  _percentProgress?.Report(90);

  SaveManifestFile(cancellationToken);
}
    
void ProcessChecksums(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  List<FileData> lstFileData = new List<FileData>();

  for (int i = 0; i < lstFilePaths.Count; i++) {
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }
            
    string s = lstFilePaths[i];
    lock (locker) queuedThreads++;

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( x => {
        manifestData.AddFileData(new FileData(s, GenerateChecksum(s)));
    });
  }

  lock (locker) {
    while (queuedThreads > 0) {
      if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }
      Monitor.Wait(locker);

      _percentProgress?.Report((((queuedThreads - lstFilePaths.Count) * -1) / lstFilePaths.Count) - 0.2);
    }
  }
}
```

There are a few other problems with the code, too. `QueueUserWorkItem` should probably be replaced with `Task.Run` and an `await Task.WhenAll` to ensure exceptions don't tear down the process. The `if (...) Finished(); else Cancelled();` is probably best represented by changing the return type to `Task`. Use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` instead of `IsCancellationRequested`. And there's a kind of `Monitor.Wait` without a `Pulse` that is just used for progress updates, which is odd; it would be cleaner to allow that code to report its own progress. If you take a look at each of these individually, you should find your code ends up cleaner.

Comment: I had a version of this that used `Task.Run` instead of the `ThreadPool` which worked nicely, but as i was essentially spinning up one thread per file for `GenerateChecksum` i was concerned with having too many threads active at a time if the directory being processed had several hundred files. (I do have a `Monitor.Pulse` at the end of the `GenerageChecksum` method, just forgot to include it)

Comment: There's no problem having lots of tasks (tasks are not threads), but most disks are not happy if you try to read hundreds of files at once. Disks tend to prefer only reading one file at a time.

Comment: I didn't think about the disk not liking the simultaneous multi-read, but sequentially reading, and then generating each checksum for a few hundred files feels like it would take much longer. Aside from loading the files into memory, then generating the checksums/performing time consuming operations on each file (assuming enough ram to do that), how would you recommend i approach this.

Comment: @Reahreic: I would recommend looking into TPL Dataflow, using one block to read files one at a time, and another block for doing the checksums.